# Flask App Running In Docker Can't Find Template

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm developing a number of micro-services and my front-end when run using docker-compose to build the front and back-end, the front-end cannot find home.html from the templates folder. When I run the app as a regular Flask app it runs fine. It's only when I incorporate Docker I have this issue.

```
├── backend
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── requirements.txt
├── deployment.yaml
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── frontend
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── templates
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── includes
│       │   ├── _formhelpers.html
│       │   ├── _messages.html
│       │   └── _navbar.html
│       └── layout.html
└── README.md
```

frontend/app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
import requests
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello_world")
def hello_world():
be_host = os.getenv('BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST', 'backend')
be_port = os.getenv('BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT', '5000')
url = 'http://{}:{}/hello_world'.format(be_host, be_port)
try:
    res = requests.get(url)
except Exception:
    return "Error with {}".format(url)
dictFromServer = res.json()
return render_template('home.html', msg=dictFromServer['message'])


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
COPY app.py /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask
requests
jsonify
```

Comment: show dockerfile too please

Comment: @nicknick updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't copied templates folder to your docker container:

```
...
COPY app.py /app
COPY templates /app/templates
...
```